# Java implicit cast in function parameters

Tags: java, casting, implicit, implicit-conversion

Is it possible to automatically cast an integer to an object when passing it as function parameter? i have this function prototype:

```
public void aggiungiA(Nodo x)
```

Nodo has his own constructor with an integer parameter. Now, What i want do is:

```
aggiungiA(5);
```

with an implicit cast.
is there anyway to do it?

Comment: There is no implicit cast (or conversion via cast) in Java.

Comment: No you cant do this directly. Consider to use somethink like factory pattern.

Answer (score 4):

There are no implicit casts via constructor invocations in java. You'll have to explicitly call the constructor - either from the caller, or by overloading the method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void aggiungiA(int i) {
        aggiungiA(new Nodo(i));
    }

    public void aggiungiA(Nodo x) {
        // Do something with X
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Mureinik's answer, I guess you are coming from a C++ background where certain casts do happen automatically. In Java things are different - the only implisit casts are:

- Widening of numeric types in expressions. For example in `long x = myLong + inInt` myInt will be cast to a long before the addition of the two long values
- Primitive values to their object equivelent. For example an 'int' is automatically cast to 'Integer' and a 'boolean' can be automatically cast to a 'Boolean'. This is called autoboxing
- Boxed objects can be cast back to their privitive values. For example an 'Integer' can be cast to an 'int' or a 'Character' to a 'char'. As this is the opposite of the previous cast it is called auto unboxing.